# Why does this autorun-cmd registry hack affect a java/maven process?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, registry, maven-surefire-plugin

The presence of an HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun causes a java test to fail. Github repo to test this out : **https://github.com/ajorpheus/final-frontier**

This is a follow-up question after **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186509)** happened.

Summary : Apparently a **[registry hack](http://www.microcenter.com/random_access/newsletters/09_newsletters/0809/toolbox_tip.html)** which allows a command to be run every time the cmd prompt is opened, adversely affects the Java process.

To begin with I thought, that perhaps it was the fact that 'mvn clean test' actually resolves to 'mvn.bat clean test'. However, I tried extracting the java.exe command contained in the mvn.bat file and tried using that directly, but got the same issue.

Any thoughts about why this might be happening ?

#### Update

Value of the Autorun entry is : `cd /d "c:\dev"`

Error message is as follows:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Error writing to file: some-dir/target/generated-resources/stuff.xmlwith the following error: Couldn't create dir: some-dir\target\generated-resources at com.test.build.TestFileCreation.createDirectoryTest`

#### Update2

As @NilsH suggested, I've confirmed that the [**current working directory**](https://github.com/ajorpheus/final-frontier/commit/b6831da764bae6fbf66ddb8ca49e807b0bd3d6eb) in both the cases is the same.

#### Update3

**[Added](https://github.com/ajorpheus/final-frontier/commit/0a997e3887c1e1f37757e8d07b288bf85ff4c69a)** a maven profile which sets maven-surefire-plugin's forkMode to never. This profile causes the test to pass irrespective of whether the registry hack is there or not.

Comment: What is the value of the reg entry? And what is the error?

Comment: @NilsH, Updated my answer with the details. These are also present in the Github repo's README : https://github.com/ajorpheus/final-frontier

Comment: Try to add `System.out.println(new File("./").getAbsolutePath());` in the test and se what the actual working directory is in both cases. That might shed some light on it. (i don't have Windows, so I can't test it)

Comment: @NilsH, The absolute path of the current working directory is the same in both the cases. I have pushed up a [**patchset**](https://github.com/ajorpheus/final-frontier/commit/b6831da764bae6fbf66ddb8ca49e807b0bd3d6eb) to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the surfire plugin execute the test in a forked environment, it starts a new cmd process. For this environment the registry hack will set the working directory to "c:\dev" and the JVM is started from within.

```
parent.exists()
```

Resolves the path against the directory from which the JVM was started. Which means the test checks the presence of file "C:/dev/some-dir/target/generated-resources/stuff.xml".

```
parent.getAbsoluteFile().exists()
```

This checks the presence of the file with it's absolute name, the one you expected to check.

see also the EVALUATION comment for this filed JDK bug
[4483097 : File returned by getAbsoluteFile() may not refer to the original file] [1](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4483097)

Comment: `When the surfire plugin execute the test in a forked environment, it starts a new cmd process`, would it be possible to have an authoritative reference for this ? Thanks !!

Comment: @AshutoshJindal Hi,
when you run maven in debug mode you see a new invokation of cmd.

`[DEBUG] boot classpath:  d:\maven\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-booter\2.14.1\surefire-booter-2.14.1.jar  ...
Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk170\jre\bin\java -jar ...`

I setup a small project using JNI to get the directory from which the JVM was invoked.
[https://github.com/SubOptimal/getcwd.git](https://github.com/SubOptimal/getcwd.git)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for taking the time out to investigate this. Awesome !!

Comment: @AshutoshJindal Thanks for the bounty points. The investigation and setting up the tiny project was a pleasure for me.