# Changing the current path in Java

Tags: java, path

I would like to set current path in Java using `java.nio.file.Path`.

Is that possible?

I know that is possible get current path using this:

```
public Path getCurrentPath() {
    Path workingDirectory = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    return workingDirectory;
}
```

Comment: No not possible. Why would you want to do the same?

Comment: what issues you face? didn't you got expected result?

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent to the `cd` command on the operating system inside a java application (see [general information about current directory](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13804).

The `current directory` for the JVM is the directory from which you start it. This information is stored in the system property `user.dir`. `java.io.File` and `java.nio.file.Path` use this information as `current directory`.

You could override this by passing `-Duser.dir=...` as JVM startup option. Which would change the current directory for `File` and `Path`.

Changing this system property at runtime with `System.setProperty("user.dir")` actually would not change the current directory. It would e.g. have an impact on what `File` assume as the current directory. `Path` still would use the directory from which the JVM was started.

For an earlier SO post [Why does this autorun-cmd registry hack affect a java/maven process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249872/why-does-this-autorun-cmd-registry-hack-affect-a-java-maven-process) I had set up a [small project](https://github.com/SubOptimal/getcwd) to demonstrate the effects.